# I wanted to bind two input textarea fields into third textarea on load i.e while typing the first ,second values

Tags: angularjs

> I have to concat the value of 1st and 2nd textarea to display in 3rd text
> I have used ng-bind to combine both values but i cannot see the combine values in UI but it is
> combined when i inspect the thirdName textarea.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<textarea ng-model="vm.firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<textarea ng-model="vm.lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<textarea ng-model="vm.thirdName" class="form-control" ng-bind ="vm.firstName + vm.lastName"
placeholder="Third Name"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If this is angular please add the tag.

Comment: This is angularjs

Comment: @User_01 You really should be using a regular text input field rather than a textarea field to capture your first name and last name fields. Last your combined field should probably just be a read only display rather than an editable field.

Comment: above solution perfectly works in my code,which one angularjs version used?

Comment: But this has to be applied in Text area only. We are using 1.5v angularjs